# My bean plants are struggling, how can I help them?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, diseases, pest-damage, beans

I'm growing three different colored beans, one is white, one is yellow, and one is red. They were growing fine, but it wasn't until about 2 weeks ago that problems started to arise. Two of them started wilting a bit, with the original three leaves it sprouted having fallen off since then and replaced by new ones. These new leaves however, have also started to wilt or form blemishes and some have different problems from one another. I've tried experimenting with the possibilities of over watering and under watering, but neither seems to be the case. No matter what, the leaves just keep wilting, at least for the two bean plants that aren't the bright green one. That one seems to have problems with rust, and is doing the best so far. So why are my other bean plants dying? Some days have been a bit cold, going into the 60 degrees fahrenheit range, while other days the sun has been out and is in the 80 degrees fahrenheit range. I've also been spraying neem oil on them every now and then because of the occurrence of bean leaf beetles that are quite large in size and some of the previous leaves that have already fallen off by now, had triangular holes in them. [image: Bean plant picture from one week ago, started showing progressively worsening symptoms]

[image: Bean plant picture from today, notice the almost completely withered bean plant on the left]

Comment: Are you fertilizing or otherwise amending the soil? If so, with what? After you spray with neem oil, do you leave the beans in the sun or in the shade? Have you actually seen the beetles on the beans?

Comment: What are the night temperatures? The plants are outdoors, correct?

Comment: What type of beans? Runners or French or something else? And are all 3 plants growing in one single smallish pot, as it looks to be the case from the image?